# How to add push notification using next-pwa

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, onesignal, next-pwa

I have a Next.js application and I use `next-pwa` for the Offline Mode. Now I want to add push notification (OneSignal solution), I've seen many articles/tutorials, and they all require to create/update the service worker.

So my question is: How can I do that since the service worker is generated by `next-pwa` and it doesn't seem to be editable since it's minified.

Answer (score 12):

You can have a look at the examples in `next-pwa` GitHub repository.

There is an example to add custom worker:
https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/custom-worker

And also another example regarding web push:
https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/web-push

Hope these few links help you!

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Go to https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/web-push and clone it.
2. Install web-push with `npm i web-push` and get the VAPID keys with `npx web-push generate-vapid-keys`
3. Create your `.env` file at the root of `web-push` directory
4. Paste your keys generated in step 2 and add your email in your .env file
5. Finally, run `npm run build` and `npm start`
   That's worked for me